# ElseIf with Dim Not Working (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code in VBA -

```
Sub KGBatch()

Dim Cognex As Variant
Cognex = Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82")

Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82:F82").Copy

If Sheets("Test").Range("A17") = "Cognex" Then
   Sheets("Test").Range("A17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

'Else: Sheets("Test").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If

End Sub
```

The Else is commented out until I figure out the first step.

I have a range in one sheet which I am copying onto a seperate sheet.  This is an easy function.  Normally the copied row will just overwrite whatever is in row 17 of the destination sheet.

'Cognex' is a six figure number which generally stays the same.  However, once in a while it changes.  When it does change I want Excel to recognise that and paste the data onto a whole new line under the previous one.

I believe I have the basics worked out, unless somebody has a better method (I'm no VBA genius!).

Currently I'm getting an error with this code though.  I've tried to Dim as lots of different variable types.

If I Dim as integer then I get an overflow error, but if I dim as Variable, string, etc. then nothing happens at all.  It just performs the Copy but no paste.

I think that's all the info I can give.  Can anybody help?

Comment: You need to `set cognex = ...`

Comment: Is the value of Cognex stored in Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82")? Is so, change that line to Cognex = Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82").Value and in the if statement, change it to If Sheets("Test").Range("A17") = Cognex Then

Comment: Thank @Sous. It was very simply a case of taking quotes off Cognex.  Od dear.

Comment: Glad I could help!  Sorry I missed out on all those sweet, sweet internet points :(

Comment: You can have some of my personal Jamsandwich points :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with a variable :

```
Sub KGBatch()

Dim Cognex As Double
Cognex = Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82").Value

Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82:F82").Copy

With Sheets("Test")
    If .Range("A17").Value = Cognex Then
       .Range("A17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Else: .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Working with a range :

```
Sub KGBatch()

Dim Cognex As Range
Set Cognex = Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82")

Sheets("KGYield").Range("B82:F82").Copy

With Sheets("Test")
    If .Range("A17").Value = Cognex.Value Then
       .Range("A17").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    'Else: .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  I seem to have fixed it by simply taking quotes off of Cognex in the If statement.  I have Dimed Cognex as Variant and it appears to be working for now.

I have a bit more work to do with this bit of code, so if I come across any issues I'll check out your solutions.

Also, thanks for reminding me to use With statements!

Comment: @Jamsandwich : I just saw that you solved this when I published my answer! Anyway, glad I could help! Good luck with your next challenges! ;)